# How to create multiple lines in a dynamic image?

Tags: php

I am using gd library for generating paragraph on image. But i still didn't find any answers.
This is the code which I was trying. Thanks

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
 $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
  or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
$text = "gfhgfhg 
hgf hgf hf hj
hgfhgfhgf hhfh 
ffgfhgf hgf hgf 
gfhgfhfhfh";
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  $text, $text_color);
imagejpeg($im, 'palette.jpg');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adapt the height of your image based on the number of lines from your text and output each line individually:

```
$text = "gfhgfhg 
hgf hgf hf hj
hgfhgfhgf hhfh 
ffgfhgf hgf hgf 
gfhgfhfhfh";

$lines = explode("\n", $text);
$letterHeight = 8;
$lineSpacing = 2;
$padding = 10;
$height = count($lines) * ($letterHeight + $lineSpacing) + $padding;

$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, $height)
  or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);

foreach ($lines as $i => $line) {
    imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5 + $i * ($letterHeight + $lineSpacing),  $line, $text_color);
}

imagejpeg($im, 'palette.jpg');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Here's a `palette.jpg` generated using the code above:

[image]

Please note that you don't need to send the `Content-type` header as you are outputting the image to a file (and not to the browser).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$text = "gfhgfhg\r\n
hgf hgf hf hj\r\n
hgfhgfhgf hhfh\r\n
ffgfhgf hgf hgf\r\n
gfhgfhfhfh";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this with [wordwrap](https://www.php.net/wordwrap) function

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
 $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
  or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
$text = "gfhgfhg 
hgf hgf hf hj
hgfhgfhgf hhfh 
ffgfhgf hgf hgf 
gfhgfhfhfh";
$text=wordwrap($text,25,"<br>\n");
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  $text, $text_color);
imagejpeg($im, 'palette.jpg');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```